# Issue with stack

Tags: c, stack, singly-linked-list

I am starting my code for stacks but here's a problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct stackNode
{
    int data;
    struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef StackNode *StackNodePtr;


void instructions()
{
    printf("Please enter a choice\n");
    printf("[1]Push a value on the stack\n");
    printf("[2]Pop a value off the stack\n");
    printf("[3]Display the whole stack\n");
    printf("[4]Exit");
} 

void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, int info)
{
    StackNodePtr newPtr;
    newPtr=malloc (sizeof ( StackNode ));
    if(newPtr !=NULL)
    {
        newPtr->data=info;
        newPtr->nextPtr=*topPtr;
        *topPtr = newPtr;
    }
}


int main()
{
    instructions();
    system("pause");
}
```

what's wrong with my code?

this is the problem

```
newPtr = malloc(sizeof (StackNode));
```

it stated invalid conversion from `void*` to `StackNode*`

compile and see if it will work

how do I fix this? what should I edit?

Comment: except the fact it's not formatted properly? What *should* happen and what *really* happens?

Comment: Could you post what the error is?  Most people aren't likely to study your code and try to figure it out without a clue as to what they should look for.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Clean the indentation pls.

Answer (score 1):

Update: as for your problem with malloc, just cast to the right type:

```
newPtr = (StackNodePtr)malloc(sizeof (StackNode));
```

---

As for the rest of the program - judging from the instructions(), you should be able to enter different choices 1, 2, 3 or 4 on the keyboard.

Your problems begin right here, you need to actually check what key "getch()" returns, like so:

```
    char c = getch();
    if (4 == c)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    if (3 == c)
    {
        display_stack();
    }
```

etc.

Also, since you have an Exit choice (4), you should probably contain all that in a loop:

```
while (1)
{
```

if-code should go in here

```
}
```

You also need to actually create the display_stack() function.

To help you with the fact that you seem to be using a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler (given the casting from malloc) you need to tell us what development environment you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As you have no return statement at the end of the main I assume you compile your code as C++, but the problem is that your code is C!

In C, you don't have to cast the return of malloc, but you have to in C++.

Take care to clearly state if you make C or C++.

If you use the GNU compiler collection, take care to use gcc and not g++ to compile a .c file.

Comment: @Kyel John M David Philippines, this is not something you can fix in the code, but you must choose in the compiler. Which development environment or compiler are you using? Borland?

Answer (score 0):

> invalid conversion from void* to StackNode*

This means you are using a C++ compiler. In C++, a conversion from `void*` to another pointer type is not permitted without a cast. In C, the conversion is allowed, so you don't need to cast the result of a call to `malloc` in C. Some argue that casting the result can mask a more fundamental issue where undeclared functions are assumed to return `int`.

Comment: @Kyel: Use a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler.